# Call to EVAL being evaluated in result portion of DO before DO runs

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, eval

The following code is intended to count down from the specified wait time and then evaluate the supplied form:

```
(defun wait (seconds form)
       (let ((end (+ (get-universal-time) seconds)))
         (do ()
          ((>= (get-universal-time) end)
           (eval form))
        (sleep 1))))
```

If I run:

```
(wait 5 (format t "output"))
```

The result is that "output" will be sent to stdout before counting down. After outputting "output" the program still counts down as usual.

I get the expected results, in which "output" is sent to stdout AFTER the countdown is complete, with the following code:

```
(defun wait (seconds form)
       (let ((end (+ (get-universal-time) seconds)))
         (do ()
          ((>= (get-universal-time) end)
           (format t "output"))
        (sleep 1))))
```

Why would the call to EVAL in the DO loop be evaluating when the DO loop is declared, but directly inserting the form being evaluated causes it to wait until result time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First law of Lisp programming for beginners: no, you don't need `eval`.**

Your function does not get a form `(foo)`, but the result of evaluating `(foo)`. All arguments to functions are evaluated BEFORE the function will be called. Lisp does not call a function with the forms of the arguments, but with the results of evaluating the arguments.

**Your code**

```
(wait                   ; function wait
  5                     ; argument expression 1
  (format t "output"))  ; argument expression 2
```

What happens?

1. `wait` is a function, get it.
2. evaluate `5` -> `5`
3. evaluate `(format t "output")` -> `NIL` + output as a side effect
4. call the function `wait` with the arguments `5` and `NIL`

**Improvement: pass a function**

If you don't want to run the argument in the call, create a function `(lambda () (foo))`, which will be evaluated to a function object, pass that to a variable `delayed-function`, and call it with `(funcall delayed-function)`.

What happens here?

```
(wait
  5
  (lambda ()
    (format t "output")))
```

1. `wait` is a function, get it.
2. evaluate `5` -> `5`
3. evaluate `(lambda () (format t "output"))` -> a function object
4. call the function `wait` with the arguments `5` and the function object

Now your function `wait` needs to do what it wants and call the passed function object at the right place - using [FUNCALL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm).

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function its arguments are evaluated once before they are passed to the function. You can use a macro if you want to pass unevaluated forms. E.g.:

```
(defmacro wait (seconds form)
  (let ((end-name (gensym "end")))
    `(do ((,end-name (+ (get-universal-time) ,seconds)))
         ((>= (get-universal-time) ,end-name))
       ,form
       (sleep 1))))
```

See its macro expansion:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(wait 10 (print 'test)))
(DO ((#:|end868| (+ (GET-UNIVERSAL-TIME) 10)))
    ((>= (GET-UNIVERSAL-TIME) #:|end868|))
  (PRINT 'TEST)
  (SLEEP 1))
```